# I am trying to run selenium through IE, but getting error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

### This is my code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class Google_ie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Testing\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerDriver fd = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        fd.get("http://www.google.com");
        fd.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
        fd.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

    }

}
```

### This is the exception which am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to find element with name == q (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 360 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:13289/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:299)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at automation.Google_ie.main(Google_ie.java:13)
```

Please suggest!!!

I Have even checked with giving some time using

Thread.sleep

but still getting the error!!!

Comment: Are you using IExplorer 11?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an IExplorer configuration problem. You must follow this steps:

- The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH.
- On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
- Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
  The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

always try to keep protected mode true for all the 5 security reasons and this error would be  resolved.
So read it from this link 
http://www.abodeqa.com/2014/11/26/challenges-to-run-selenium-webdriver-scripts-in-ie-browser/

Comment: The above issue is not a "protected mode" issue. Newer versions of selenium give you a much more specific message if that is the case.  So, it's likely a different reason.

Comment: Downvoting for two reasons. First, it's a link-only answer. Second, and more importantly, the page linked to gives no insights **why** the solutions are required. This leads to copy-paste development, with no understanding for the user. There are much better articles on the topic on sites other than the one linked to here.